# How to associate median with angles??

Tags: geometry

I have got an olympiad problem which is like follow:

In  triangle ABC,let D be the midpoint of BC.If  ∠ADB=45 and ∠ACD=30 ,determine ∠BAD.

The main problem with the question is that the given things are two angles and a median.I don't know how to relate these two (Appolonius's theorem won't work).

Any suggestion is heartily welcome.

Comment: Give precise reference to this olympiad. It may help everybody. And provide a graphics for a geometrical problem. It takes such a short time...

Comment: @JeanMarie,it is a question asked in regional mathematical olympiad in India.I will surely mention the details of olympiad if I found it significant (such as problems of national olympiad problems or IMO)

Comment: All right, I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: note that $\widehat{CAD} = 15^\circ $ and $\widehat{ABD} + \widehat{BAD} = 135^\circ$. Apply the sine law twice to get:

$$\frac{AD}{CD} = \frac{\sin 30^\circ}{\sin 15^\circ} = \frac{\sin(135^\circ -\widehat{BAD})}{\sin \widehat{BAD}} $$

Comment: Given that this suggests $30^\circ$ there may be a simpler approach  - but as my own approach  would give $\tan^{-1}(1)-\tan^{-1}(2-\sqrt{3})$, I cannot really complain

Comment: I am surprised that this answer is validated, even as a hint.

Comment: @JeanMarie There is nothing wrong with posting (or accepting) hints as answers, even more so when the OP asks for "*any suggestion heartily welcome*". See for example the meta discussion [Do hints belong in answers or comments?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10589/do-hints-belong-in-answers-or-comments). In the particular case here, my hint effectively solves the problem by reducing it to a trig equation which is straightforward to solve, especially for someone working on olympiad level problems.

Comment: I understand. The remark was addressed to the asker. The fact that he is a practitioner of Olympiads is a point. But precisely, why is he not answering to my question about his sources ?

Comment: @JeanMarie,because I wasn't on site for a while.

Answer (score 3):

Without trigonometry.

Let point $B'$ be such that triangle $AB'C$ is equilateral and $B$ and $B'$ lie on the same side of line $AC.$ Let point $C'$ be such that line $AC'$ is orthogonal to $B'C$ and $AC' = AC = AB' = B'C$. By construction, $AC'$ is the orthgognal bisector of $B'C$ so $$B'C' = CC'\,\,\, \text{ and } \,\,\, \angle \, CAC' = B'AC' = 30^{\circ}$$ Therefore, triangles $CAC'$ and $B'AC'$ are congruent isosceles triangles with $30^{\circ}$ internal angle at vertex $A$ (because $AC'$ is the angle bisector of equlateral triangle $AB'C$).

[image]

Now, by assumption, $\angle \, DAC = \angle \, ADB - \angle \, ACD = 45^{\circ} - 30^{\circ} = 15^{\circ}$. Hence, line $AD$ is the angle bisector in isosceles triagnle $CAC'$ through vertex $A$ and so $AD$ is also orthogonal bisectror of $CC'$ which means that $DC = DC'$. A direct angle chasing shows that $\angle \, CDC' = 90^{\circ}$. However, by assumption, $BD = DC = DC'$ so $$BC ' = CC' = B'C' \,\,\, \text{ and } \,\,\, \angle \, BC'C = 90^{\circ}$$ Hence triangle $BB'C'$ is isosceles and after a direct angle chasing, one sees that $\angle \, BC'B' = 60^{\circ}$. Thus $BB'C'$ is an equilateral triangle. This means that triangles $ABC'$ and $ABB'$ are congruent, because $BB' = BC'$, segment $AB$ is common and $AB'=AC'$ by construction. Therefore, $$\angle \, BAB' = \angle \, BAC' = \frac{1}{2} \, \angle \, B'AC' = \frac{1}{2} \, 30^{\circ} = 15^{\circ}$$ We can cocnlude that $$\angle \, BAC = \angle \, BAC' + \angle CAC' = 15^{\circ} + 30^{\circ} = 45^{\circ}$$

Comment: +1 for figuring out the reason why those particular values $30^\circ,45^\circ$ were chosen. @THELONEWOLF You can always change your accept vote, and there is no problem with that.

Comment: I said I wish I could accept 2 answers.@futurologist Sorry for that but I won't change my acceptence because the earlier answer(given by dxiv) is quite easy and one which I can easily describe to my fellows.However I am very thankful to have a great answer given by you.

Comment: Very interesting. Like yours, my answer has needed the introduction of the altitude issued from A (your AB'). A little detail: I think that your  'Without trigonometry" at the beginning should be "Without any circular function" because using angles is doing trigonometry...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution uniquely based on computations of tangents. See figure below.

A preliminary result: $\tan(15^\circ)=2-\sqrt{3}.$

(this can be done by different ways, for example by using $\tan(a+b)=\dfrac{\tan(a)+\tan(b)}{1-\tan(a)\tan(b)}$ with $a=b$ and solving a quadratic; taking into account that $\tan(30^\circ)=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$)

We may assume WLOG that $BD=DC=1$. Let $H$ be the projection of $A$ onto straight line $BC$. Let $a=\bar{HB}$, this overbar meaning oriented length $HB$ (with respect to an axis $BC$ directed by vector $\vec{BC}$ (we don't know, at this step, whether $H$ is inside or outside line segment $BC$). Thus:

$$\begin{cases}\text{In triangle AHD:} \ \ & \tan(45^{\circ})=1=\dfrac{h}{a+1}\\
\text{In triangle AHC:} \ \ & \tan(30^{\circ})=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}=\dfrac{h}{a+2}\end{cases}$$

These two equations give:

$$a=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{3}}{2}\ \ \text{and} \ \ h=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Note that $a>0$. Thus $H$ is outside $BC$.

We are now able to compute:  $\tan{\widehat{HAB}} = \dfrac{a}{h}=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{3}}{1+\sqrt{3}}=2-\sqrt{3}=\tan(15^\circ)$

As $AHB$ is a right triangle, $\widehat{HAC}= 90^\circ-\widehat{ACH}=60^\circ .$

Thus: $\widehat{BAC}=\widehat{HAC}-\widehat{HAB}=60^\circ-15^\circ=45^\circ.$

[image]